# how to supress or get rid of Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null warning in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, themes

My problem is simple that their is a boolean variable x which calls for a flag from shared Preference telling the app that it's dark mode or light mode theme.

issue here is i cannot assign a default value to it as if i do the default will be used to set the value of theme every time i need to i restart the app.

a similar question on stack indicates a good solution of applying a loader before if the value of x is null. but i need x out of scaffold and not in side it on start. you can see the code below which can help you understand my problem.

the error code is only shown on ios for a mere 1 sec or less but it's visible. on android i am not facing that issue. at least on my device.
after that fraction of second. i have no issue.

what i have tried is giving a default value and it didn't worked as mentioned above.

```
bool x;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    ThemeChanger.currentState().then((val) {
      print("value of val: $val");
      setState(() {
        x = val;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeChanger>(
        builder: (_) => ThemeChanger((x) ? ThemeChanger.customDarkTheme : ThemeChanger.customLightTheme),
        child: new MaterialAppWithTheme(),
      );
  }
```

is there a way i can use the shared Preference much faster or show loading screen / circular progress before this code and wait for the future to get value from the shared Preference ?

Comment: can you also provide the full error that throws in iOS?

Comment: ``` flutter: Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null ``` this is it. for the the screen short its not even possible as for a sec or so, it is displayed on device.

Comment: can you try this :ThemeChanger((x ?? false) ? ThemeChanger.customDarkTheme : ThemeChanger.customLightTheme)

Comment: yes i have tried that and as what i told above, the default theme will only be shown each time. unless i change it again for the current app cycle. it's equivalent to setting a default value to x.

Comment: i think your only solution is to return a placeholder widget like SizedBox() in your build when x is null

Comment: this is the starting point of the app. where will i put that thing ? also i don't have splash screen as of now. but is their a way that i might load the data from the splash screen and then use it every where in the app without shared preference coming in to action ?

Comment: in your build method in code above, yes you can load data in your splash screen when currentState.then((val) => ... is called you can use a flag to check if it's the first time and then navigate to the next route

Answer (score 1):

I think it's too late to answer but here is solution:
In dart you can not declare boolean value null so you have to define either true or false.

bool x = true;